# How to use k-nn algorithm in Java Script?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I need to use a k-nn algorithm in my application. I am using node.js to run my application and I would like to use this implementation of k-nn: https://github.com/aschuch/node-nearest-neighbor .

The problem is, how can I call the function to execute the k-nn in my angular.js controller function instead of in my app.js?

I already tried to do `knn = require('nearest-neighbor')` but didn't worked. I tried `knn = document.createElement('nearest-neighbor')` but didn't worked too. Sometimes I got error in a `exports` inside the `nearest-neighbor.js` and sometimes it says that `findMostSimilar` is not a function.

How can I execute this algorithm?

Comment: Sounds like you're mixing up the client and the server. angular is client-side while node.js runs on the server.

Comment: So, I need to pass the data to the server side, in this case, the node or my app.js and after I apply the knn, I return the items found to the angular.js controller?

Comment: You could try using [browserify](http://browserify.org/). It successfully converts many node.js scripts so that they can run in a browser. If you use that then `knn = require('nearest-neighbour')` might work.